# How do I get LaTeX to show the output of "ls" like it is formatted?

Tags: bash, shell, latex, ls

I'm trying to write a shellscript which uses LaTeX, ls, and some other commands to export a list of files and directories inside a given directory, and a full printout of all bash scripts inside the given directory.
This is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to export directory with pdflatex

# Generate .tex file
# Directory Listing
echo "\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}" > tmp.tex
echo "\usepackage{fullpage}" >> tmp.tex
echo "\begin{document}" >> tmp.tex
echo "\section{Listing}" >> tmp.tex
ls $1 >> tmp.tex

echo "\end{document}" >> tmp.tex

# ShellScript printout

# Generate .pdf file
pdflatex tmp.tex

#Cleanup
rm tmp.tex
```

The problem is, however, that the "ls" command does function right in the terminal, but when fed to LaTeX it gets printed as a space-devided line instead of a list. How do I fix this?

And concerning the shellscript printout; if you have any ideas on how to print these..

Many thanks,
Gerard

Comment: can't answer now that it's closed, but you probably want `ls -C` -- when output does not go to a terminal, ls implicitly uses the `-1` option.

Comment: Why didn't they just move it to latex stack exchange?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '\begin{verbatim}' >> tmp.tex
ls "$1" >> tmp.tex
echo '\end{verbatim}' >> tmp.tex
```

should do what you want unless there is a file named '`\end{verbatim}`' in the directory being listed (yes, this is possible).  If that's something you need to worry about, you need two files and the `\VerbatimInput` command from the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) add-on package.

Comment: you could also use a here document `cat <<< "\begin{verbatim}$(ls "$1")\end{verbatim}"`

Comment: Thanks! You've just resolved that issue that was taking me an hour trying to figure out!